# UISegmentController not visible in a popover on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, popover

I have a UISegmentController that is being presented in a navigation bar in a `UIPopoverController'. The segmented control is build in the xib file right above table view.

This seems to work on iOS 7, but on iOS 8 the segment controller is not even showing up in a popover. Why would that be?

Any help is appreciated.